# Can't reset permissions on amazon ec2

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, permissions

I've a big problem:

when I try to sudo something, this is what append:

```
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 222, should be 0
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 222, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I tried to detach volume and retach it into a new istance, then I mount it and I set right permission also with chown and chmod: doesn't work.

I also tried this:

```
chown root:root /etc/sudoers
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
chown -R root:root /etc/sudoers.d
chmod  755 /etc/sudoers.d
chmod  440 /etc/sudoers.d/*
```

same result: doesn't work.
Worse I can't connect to ssh.

How can I fix this ?

here debug with -vv:

```
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ec2-user: Name or service not known
```

Really thanks for support.

Comment: What happens when you try to connect via ssh?

Comment: sometimes it rejects ppk key, and sometimes connection time out: really strange thing, even if istance is running...

Comment: Have you tried applying any flags to ssh, to debug? If not, try -vv, and see what that tells you.

Comment: No, I'm trying now with ssh -vv: wait.

Comment: Now connection is time out. can't do anything, just mount in another istance...

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't look good. I would try looking at the security groups and network ACLs associated with the box, to make sure it's reachable. Beyond that, I'm not sure what else you can do. Good luck.

Comment: good I can access: debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ec2-user: Name or service not known

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution:

I used rsync to change file from an old snapshot to the mounted instance.
This solve the problem.